# modeling global indentification for different objects in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, data-modeling

I have a system where I want a global identifier for objects in rails. The global identification is a number (or alpha-numeric) that is shared across a bunch of objects. When you save an object you will insert a global identificaiton value that is based upon an object and an object_id.

So for example:

```
location id=3

id=15
arc_type='location'
arc_id=3
arc_value=loc-3
```

So the question is can I do a has_one using a composite foreign key of object_type and object_id. Or would I need to a foreign key like the object value, a shortened name and the id of the original object.

Or perhaps use a different scenario such as an md5 hash as foreign key.

Would this be a candidate for doing a polymorphic association? It seems like that would be more appropriate for the has_many rather than has_one (such as pictuers or comments). Has anyone ever done a has_one with a polymorphic assoication?

thx

edit - looks like the object_id name is a bad idea so i've substituted arc_ which is initials of project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the composite foreign key in Rails since the `has_one` association only seems to have `:primary_key` and `:foreign_key` options. See more [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-association-reference).

I have accomplished something very similar to this recently though. At a high level, I added a `uuid` field to all the models that I want to uniquely identify along with a shared bit of code that generates the UUID on save. Now that each object has a unique identifier, I can use Rail's `:primary_key` and `:foreign_key` to build associations as I please. Here's the breakdown:

I used the [uuidtools](https://github.com/sporkmonger/uuidtools/tree/) gem to generate a universally unique id.

```
Gemfile.rb
gem 'uuidtools'
```

Then I created some helper methods in app/models to ensure that a UUID is generated and set whenever an ActiveRecord model is created or saved.

```
uuid_helper.rb

module UUIDHelper
  def self.append_features(base)
    base.before_create { |model| base.set_uuid_if_empty(model) }
    base.before_save { |model| base.set_uuid_if_empty(model) }

    def base.set_uuid_if_empty(model)
      if column_names.include?('uuid') and model.uuid.blank?
        model.uuid = UUIDTools::UUID.random_create().to_s
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Finally, I make sure that my models of interest have a `uuid` field of type string and set up my associations.

```
Thing.rb

class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  include UUIDHelper

  belongs_to :user, :primary_key => 'uuid', :foreign_key => 'owner'
end


User.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include UUIDHelper

  has_many :thing, :primary_key => "uuid", :foreign_key => "owner"
end
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Nicely detailed answer. It looks like you can indeed set up a `has_one` with a polymorphic association: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-as

Comment: so is there a central table that manages this? I have a table called globals_lists where there are lists of these global_ids but I'm not sure how this would mesh with that. My current implementation uses a central table called global_identification

Comment: No central table necessary. Instead, each model has a `uuid` column (which can be added with a [migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-migration)).

Comment: the problem is that this doesn't provide the ability to resolve into a third table. Say, you want a list of items that are managed by list_id and global_id. there is no way to reconcile a uuid that is in each table.